# URL that takes user to DocuSign document to be signed, not logged in

Tags: xml, url, docusignapi

I need a URL that will take the user to a document that is to be signed. I'm aware of the embedded signing API call that will take the user to the document already signed in. But in the system I'm trying to incorporate DocuSign functionality into, I need a link that will take the user directly to the document, require them to sign in, and then do as they please with the document. I have an server set up to receive DocuSign XML events and believe I can configure what gets sent to it and thus have quite a bit of data to be able to build the URL. I'm just not positive if this is possible or not. Would I just need the envelope ID? Do I need to make an API call of some sort to generate this link? This is tricky because the key difference between the embedded signing API call and what I'm trying to achieve is that the user is not already signed in upon clicking the link.

I've done a bit of searching and haven't been able to find someone with this task exactly. If anyone could shed some light on if this is possible or an easy way to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot generate a signing URL for someone who is a remote (non-embedded) signer. Embedded signers themselves are never associated to an account so it's impossible to require them to login to sign an envelope.

You can however, edit the login requirements for remote signers in an envelope, that's done under Preferences -> Features -> Signer Login Requirements. But, when those envelopes are created an email is still sent to the recipient, once they click the link in the email then they are required to login before signing.

Comment: Really? So there's no other way I can direct someone to a document to be signed without using the embedded signing URL that is returned from the API call?

Comment: What do you think about doing this:     **demo.docusign.net/Member/MemberLogin.aspx?e={envelopeID}&loginended=true**... can you think of a time where this would not work? I'm able to retrieve the envelopeID from XML that is sent to my server. This seems to simulate a signer being on the document being signed and then the session expiring, forcing the user to sign back in. Do you see anything wrong with creating that link?

Comment: @Caleb - I just tested this myself and it works brilliantly! One thing that could be confusing to the signer is that the login page itself does say "your session has timed out."

The other problem is that your signer will still get the email to sign the envelope, the ONLY way to prevent this is to have them change their email notification settings. But to prevent this in the future, as the admin of the account can go to Preferences -> Features -> Email Notifications and remove all the checkboxes for "I am a Signer." This will only change defaults for NEW users created after the change is made

Comment: I found that removing the "&loginended=true" from the URL removes that message and does the same thing, taking the user directly to the document while requiring them to log in. So all users under the "master admin" account will inherit that email notification setting? Yeah I definitely don't want the emails going through.

Comment: Correct, all users will inherent the settings you set through Features, not through Member Profile --> Manage Email Notifications. But again, that is only going forward, so you will want to set those email notification settings prior to creating your users.

Comment: Awesome, good to know. Thanks a ton for the help man, I'll set your comment as accepted answer